# Python 3.4 - tkinter - arduino - binary to float?

Tags: python, tkinter, binary, arduino

I'm trying to use an arduino to send temperature data via USB to Python.  I'm displaying that data in a tkinter label and that works fine.  However, it looks like the data is a binary string and I'm trying to do a comparison (if reading is greater than x; do y).  I'm quite the newb, so I don't understand why the label displays correctly, but when I simply "print" the value, it shows up as a binary string.  The label displays 69.25 but the print command displays b'69.25/r/n'. Unless someone has a better idea of how to accomplish this, I think I need to convert the binary to a float so I can do the math. Here is the relevant portion of the code.

```
ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 115200, timeout=.1)
        def update():
            while 1:
                reading.set(ser.readline())
                root.update()
                sleep(2)
                xxx=reading.get()
                print(xxx)

        reading=StringVar(root)
        CurrentTempLabel=Label(root,textvariable=reading)

root.after(1,update)
```

Comment: Please clarify. What is a binary string? If you're just asking "how do I convert a string to a float?", then do `my_float_value = float(my_string)`

Comment: Do you really have `b'69.25/r/n'` rather than `b'69.25\r\n'`?

Comment: sorry...yes.  it is actually b'69.25\r\n'

Answer (score 2):

First, I'm willing to bet you actually have the bytes `b'69.25\r\n'`, not `b'69.25/r/n'`. The former is 5 characters followed by a carriage return and newline; the latter is 5 characters followed by a slash, an `r`, a slash, and an `n`.

Now, if you have the `bytes` value `b'69.25\r\n'`, and it represents the number `69.25`, then it's just representing the float as a string in some encoding. Since the only characters in that string are going to be the ASCII characters `0123456789+-.Ee\r\n`, it doesn't even really matter *which* encoding, as long as it's basically ASCII-compatible. So:

```
>>> b = b'69.25\r\n'
>>> s = b.decode('ascii')
>>> s
'69.25\r\n'
>>> f = float(s)
>>> f
69.25
```

---

So, why does it "just work" when you stick it in a tkinter Label? Because when you give tkinter a `bytes`, it decodes it using your default encoding, which is almost certainly ASCII-compatible, and when you pass a `bytes` or `str` with multiple lines to a single-line control, it ignores everything after the newline.

---

If you really do have `/r/n`, not `\r\n`, then hopefully they were just placed there by an error in whatever's running on the other end and you can just ignore them. Fortunately, none of those characters can appear in a valid float, so we can be a little hacky and do this:

```
>>> b = b'69.25/r/n'
>>> s = b.decode('ascii')
>>> s
'69.25/r/n'
>>> stripped = s.rstrip('rn/')
>>> stripped
'69.25'
>>> f = float(stripped)
>>> f
69.25
```

Comment: i'm using Python 3.4 so no .decode, right?  it seemed to work as expected when entered at the python prompt, but when I try to .decode my reading in the program, i get the error 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'.  When I tried converting by float(reading), i get the error, could not convert string to float: "b' ' "

Comment: @MarkZ: In Python 3.4, there very definitely is a `decode` on `bytes` objects. There's no `decode` on `str` objects, but that's not what you said you had in the question, and now what I showed in the answer.

Comment: @MarkZ: If you've converted the `bytes` to `str` somewhere along the way by doing `str(b)`, then that would explain the no `decode`, and the other problems—but then the answer is, wherever you did that, don't do that, and instead do `b.decode('ascii')`.

Comment: @MarkZ: One last thing: In Python 3.4, `float` _sometimes_ works directly on `bytes` without decoding them. But this doesn't always work, and according to the docs should not work, and you definitely don't want to rely on it.

Comment: I didn't convert the bytes to str.  The arduino is sending the data via Serial.println(f,2).  I tried changing that to Serial.write(f) instead (f is of type float), but got a compile error.

Comment: @MarkZ Serial.write() is expecting bytes so won't like the float. You need to do something like: byte * b = (byte *) &f; 
 Serial.write(b,4); and your python end would need to read four bytes at a time. All a lot more complicated than println and readline

Comment: So I tried to assign another variable to the different characters in the string and got weird results.  The "string" X is: "b'69.25\r\n" and when i assign a=x[0], b=x[1], c=x[2] and print(a+b+c), i get b'6; as expected.  But if I add d=x[3], i get an error saying "string index out of range".  Why is that not the next character?

Comment: So its pretty ugly, but I got it to work. the reason d=x[3] failed was because the first 3 lines sent from the arduino is just b''...once the sensor starts sending data, the length goes up to 12 characters.  So I simply said, if len(x)!=3: then assign a new variable to x[2] through x[6], joined them together, converted to float and it works fine.  I can now do my comparison.  I don't quite understand it, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

the b prefixed string means it's a byte rather than unicode object.

*look at using struct.unpack() I think that's the standard way (what I've used anyway) - then put the actual float value into the string using "...{}...".format(val)

https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

*EDIT as @abamert comments this would be a more complicated step, as you are already sending from the arduino using println() and the python read is getting a string. However if processing time was a factor (as in a control system) then there are two unnecessary conversions to and from floats/strings so it might then be worth switching the arduino code to use write(), in which case you would need to use use struct.unpack in python.

Comment: No, if the bytes are `b'69.25/r/n'` and the value represented is `69.25`, he doesn't want to use `struct.unpack`…